# I can't get key code to match a value in an array

Tags: javascript

I am making a game, and I am trying to get a keycode to match a letter I have in an array.

When I press any key on the keyboard, I get the message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Does anyone know a simple solution to this?

```js
var list = ["hi", "bye", "fun", "cool", "good"];
var randomItem;
var keyPressed;
var letters;
var i;

function play(event) {
  var keyPressed = event.keyCode;
  var keyPressedChar = String.fromCharCode(keyPressed);
  console.log("Keyboard press works: " + keyPressed);
  splitWord();
  checkValue();

}

function splitWord() {
  var letters = randomItem.split('');
  console.log(letters);
}

function nyttOrd() {
  randomItem = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
  document.getElementById("word").innerText = "The word is: " + randomItem;

  splitWord();

}

function checkValue() {
  for (i = 0; i < randomItem.length; i++) {
    if (letters[i] == keyPressed) {
      console.log("Okey");
    } else {
      console.log("Not Okey");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="nyttOrd()" onkeydown="play(event)">
  <div id="word"></div>
```

Comment: Remove `var` in front of `letters` in `splitWord`; that redefines the variable locally.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you print keyPressedChar instead of keyPressed? The way you are printing keyPressed now will convert the object to a string which probably defaults to 0

Answer (score 0):

Your `letters` variable at line 4 is global for the scope of the script, but it is never initialized
in the splitWord() function you have a local variable `var letters` never setting the value to the global var, and thus an error is thrown in the `checkValue()` function because letters was never initialized but you're trying to access `letters[i]`